# NSString method deprecated, but replacement not there?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am (re)building a project written in objective c in XCode 3.2.6 64 bit under a 10.6.8 VM based on the 10.5 SDK (for compatibility with 10.5 and up - so this is a given.) The build is up and working. But. I'm trying to address the last four warnings in this project. They're all the same warning. Specifically...

In the project, there are four ASCII c strings that need to be converted to four corresponding instances of objective c's NSString. There are four essentially identical cases. This is how it's being done:

```
[tf setStringValue: [NSString stringWithCString: strg]]
```

This works, but results in (four) warnings that `stringWithCString is deprecated` and looking further, I find that's been true since about 10.4. So I'd expect the 10.5 SDK to have whatever replacement is required.

Looking at the docs, the suggested replacement is:

```
[tf setStringValue: [NSString stringWithCString:NSASCIIStringEncoding: strg]]
```

However, when this is used, XCode says:

```
'NSString' may not respond to '+stringWithCString::'
```

Which probably means it really won't respond. And besides, even if it does, replacing one warning with another.... yech.

Anyone know what I should be doing differently? I realize that this is old, old stuff, but surely Back In The Day people didn't just let these warnings clutter up their builds? Have I just got some kind of syntax error here, or... ?

Answer (score 3):

> `[NSString stringWithCString:NSASCIIStringEncoding: strg]`

The correct syntax for calling [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497310-stringwithcstring?language=objc) is:

```
[NSString stringWithCString:strg encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```